# chartjs display stats with a doughnut, but get no legend and infos of pices

Tags: reactjs, typescript, chart.js

i am using chartjs to show some infos. It works so far but if i hover over one pice of the doughnut i didnt get shown the infos of this pice. And the legend didnt get shown. I dont know what the problem is...

```
import {UserGameDTO} from "../service/model";
import {Doughnut} from "react-chartjs-2"
import {Chart, ArcElement} from "chart.js"
Chart.register(ArcElement);

interface gameDoughnutProps{
    Game: UserGameDTO
}

export function GameDoughnut(props: gameDoughnutProps){


    const options = {
        responsive: true,
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                position: 'top' as const,
            },
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: "test",
            },
        },
    }
    
    const doughnutData = {
        labels: [
            'Red',
            'Blue',
            'Yellow'
        ],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Spent money',
            data: [props.Game.spentMoneyGame, props.Game.spentMoneyCoins, props.Game.spentMoneyGamePass],
            borderColor: "black",
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgb(243,121,147)',
                'rgb(97,172,227)',
                'rgb(234,198,115)'
            ],
            hoverOffset: -10
        }],
    };

    return(
        <Doughnut options={options} data={doughnutData}/>
    )
}
``
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import and register everything you are using if you are using treeshaking, so in your case you also need to import the legend and tooltip and register those.

```js
import {Chart, Legend, Tooltip} from 'chart.js';

Chart.register(Legend, Tooltip);
```

Or you can let chart.js handle everything for you and use this import

```js
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';
```